# scrollToRowAtIndexPath with UITableView does not work

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have in iOS8 a table view like this:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain)
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

When the user types and sends some text in the keyboard, the application ivoke the following method to scroll the tableView. The goal is to view the new text in the screen (like a chat)

```
let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: 0)
            tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
        }
```

But the table view does not scroll to the bootom.

Someone has a solution?

Thank you.

Explanation:

Definition of the class:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate
```

then I have the definition of the table view:

```
var tableView: UITableView!
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain) 
tableView.dataSource = self 
tableView.delegate = self 
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

then I have the call to the code that should make the scroll (second block of code on my answer). 
When I launch the application I expect the tableview to scroll down, but it does not work.

Answer (score 89):

The solution below worked for me. It's a combination of solutions found on StackOverflow. I called "`scrollToRowAtIndexPath`" after a very short delay.

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

    let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections()
        let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
        }

    })
}
```

called by :

```
tableViewScrollToBottom(true)
```

**Swift 3**

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
        let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
        let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I found so far. I had to increase the delay to 0.5 though otherwise it would sometimes be called before tableView.reloadData has finished. I tried about every solution on SO (subclass `TableViewDelegate` and override `reloadData`; execute on main thread with `dispatch_asynch`, etc.) to scroll to bottom, none of them seem to work anymore for **iOS 9**.

Comment: iOS 9 broke other methods for scrolling to the bottom of a table. But this one works.

Comment: This didn't help me ....I have to scroll manually to see the contents for last row. there is nothing wrong with table view and its content size because manual scroll shows the contents properly.

Comment: It works but i wonder if there is any way to do this without dispatch after?

Comment: Using "DispatchQueue" worked for me too in 2019, with Swift 5. scrollToRow was not working without delaying it by using "DispatchQueue". Can someone please explain its reason? Why a delay is necessary?

Comment: scrollToRow is one of the most frustrating things to use in iOS. I am already adding a delay but sometimes it doesn't scroll all the way through the bottom.

Comment: Works in 2020 for my related issue - thanks for the idea! For info I had some bad behaviour when scrolling to a position *during a scrollView bounce*. i.e. if the scrollView is still offset from a scroll bounce, jumping to a certain scroll position can misbehave. Delaying the scrollToRow by 100ms cleaned this up. Perfecto.

Answer (score 11):

The solution at my problem is:

```
let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections()
let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

if numberOfRows > 0 {
    println(numberOfSections)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: cause crash in `let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)` if `numberOfSections` is 0

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT 3 VERSION of @Fox5150 answer, with an extension :**

```
extension UITableView {

    func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {

            let numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections
            let numberOfRows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)
            if numberOfRows > 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
self.tableView.tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try reloading first before calling scroll. Very weired but works for iOS8.

```
   tableView.reloadData()
   tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
```

Comment: I needed to update a table view's scroll position that isn't visible when the scroll is taking place and this worked for me. Tested on iOS9. Also, It's not that it didn't scroll, but it didn't scroll completely in all instances. Now it does.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 Version**

```
extension UITableView {
  func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
      let numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections
      let index = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
      if index > 0 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index-1, section: 0)
        self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: animated)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**You can use like:**

```
[YOUR_TABLE_VIEW].tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: [TRUE])
```

Comment: perfect ...you save my ass

Answer (score 2):

I have the problem with a bigger index say even 15. Only indexes till 5-6 use to work. By making "animated: false" scrollToRowAtIndexPath() worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Just do the scroll operation in **viewDidLayoutSubViews()**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollToBottom(animated: false)
}

fileprivate func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    if self.items.count > 0 {
        let lastIndex = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 1)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndex, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

It seems like tableview could get the correct positon after layout subviews.

Answer (score 2):

I go the same problem in late 2020.

Since i really did not want some magic dispatch-timeout, i played around a bit. What helped (and was not mentioned here before) was a forced layout for the UITableView:

```
_viewTable.layoutIfNeeded()
_viewTable.scrollToRow(at:IndexPath(row:index, section:0), at:.middle, animated:false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to flip upside down the tableView so you can show new message just by
 `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

to do it you need first to flip your table by:

```
_tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);
```

then don't forget to flip back your cells, best place to do it in -awakeFromNib by subclassing:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);

//if you have accessoryView
    self.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);
}
```

Comment: WHAT IS THIS SORCERY

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by calling `scrollToRow()` in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: ROW, section: SECTION), at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keyboard is still visible you have to set the `UITableView`'s `contentInset` property to compensate for the keyboard height at the bottom of the screen. Otherwise your cell might be hidden behind the keyboard because the `UITableView` doesn't know that half of its content is hidden by it.

Or use a `UITableViewController` which handles that automatically.

Comment: A little more context is necessary then. Can you share more code please?

Comment: Definition of the class:

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate

the definition of the table view:

var tableView: UITableView!
in viewDidLoad:

tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain)
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(tableView)

... cal to the code that sould make the scroll (second block of code on my answer).

When I launch the application I expect the tableview scrolls down, but does not work

Comment: Please edit your original question to add new code. This is barely readable.

Comment: This is still not enough code to understand how and when you scroll to the last cell. Can you show the whole process from the point where the message is added until the scroll happens (which you already posted)? -- You should also check out [SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/) - maybe you find it helpful as it seems to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Call scrollToLastPosition() method after loading the tableview like call from viewWillAppear( ) or after table view reload when some thing changed into tableview

```
func scrollToLastPosition() {
 if !message.isEmpty {
    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: message.count - 1 , inSection:     0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexpath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres Swift 3 version

```
let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)

if numberOfRows > 0 {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row: numberOfRows-1, section: numberOfSections-1)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First figure out how many sections there are
 let lastSectionIndex = self.tblTableView!.numberOfSections() - 1

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section

let lastRowIndex = 
self.tblTableView!.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1

// Now just construct the index path

let pathToLastRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: lastRowIndex, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

// Make the last row visible
self.tblTableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(pathToLastRow, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

All above codes are fine, but in my case when I want to load the `tableView` as well as scroll to bottom of the `tableView` **instantly** when the **controller loads**, for that situation above methods are taking some time to scroll to the bottom of the `tableView`. So I have followed these codes.

Override `tableView` reload as

```
extension UITableView
{
    func reloadData(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: { self.reloadData() })
        { _ in completion() }
    }
}
```

Written scroll to bottom method as follows:

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom
{
     if self.tblChat.contentSize.height > self.tblChat.frame.size.height
     {
         let offset:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y :self.tblChat.contentSize.height-self.tblChat.frame.size.height)
         self.tblChat.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
     }
 }
```

and then reload `tableView` when data loads completes from web service or from any core data entity:

```
tblChat.reloadData()
{
     self.tableViewScrollToBottom
}
```

Now its working smooth as I wanted.

Comment: This is not scrolling at all. And please, check the code as you're not using the arguments parentheses in your func

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an older thread, but it's still relevant. Instead of dealing with timeouts that could sometimes fail to be well timed, use synchronous blocks on the main thread (normally not something I'd do, but we're talking milliseconds):

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
  // Reload code goes here...
  tableView.reloadData()
}

DispatchQueue.main.sync {
  // Row, section and other checks / initialization go here...
  tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

This always works for me.

Comment: I will never support this solution as blocking main thread simply does not mean that we are just blocking UI, we might be blocking something else running on that queue.