# scroll a UITableViewCell to top of the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

i have a tableView with three rows in it now i want to move my cell2 to top of the tableView so that **Cell1 become totally invisible (out of the tableView's bounds )**

this is what i tried :

```
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    let index = NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(index, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)

}
```

the above did nothing , maybe i'm missing something there

i also tried this :

```
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    let cgpoint = CGPointMake(0, (CGFloat(-64 - (channelCellRowHeight )))) // channelCellRowHeight is the hight of my row which i want move outside the tableview so that cell2 can stay at top of tableview 
    // here cgpoint is not accurate  
    tableView.setContentOffset(cgpoint, animated: true)
  }
```

i wonder there must be simpler way to do it something like 
`scrollRowToTop` api

any clue how can i achieve what i want ??

Comment: You need to calculate the height of all the cells you want to move to top and set them as the Y position of your contentOffset

Comment: You found the solution?

Comment: man i'm having problem while calculating my row height , this is what i'm doing : `let frame = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
        defaultRowHeight = frame.height` @MohammedShakeer but what to do with this then ? cause my default contentOffset is `(0.0, -64.0)` (when tableView rows are at their default position)

Comment: got it working man , just needed a small calculation. thanks for responding :)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26267196) could help

Answer (score 1):

if your table view cells have different cell heights then you need to implement this delegate method so the table view can calculate an accurate cell height value to be able to scroll the cell for your desired position

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText;
cellText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:cellText
 attributes:@
 {
 NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
 }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
return rect.size.height;
}
```

Hope this answer helps you