# TableView scrollToRow is blocking the main ui thread

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with about 500 items.

When i call `tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)` the main UI thread is getting blocked for 3 seconds.

Is there a way to fix this? or is the problem scrolling 500 items?

Thanks

---

the problem is not with `reloadData` it was with `scrollToRow`

Comment: You should use lazy loading. It would helps you more smooth scroll.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: @kayzersoze what should be lazy? the tableView?

Comment: @SnehaGeorge what part? i'm only getting a JSON from server parsing it a calling reloadData, and the ui thread is getting blocked on the reloadData

Comment: What's your code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` That could be where your issue lies. If you scroll yourself fast, do you have the issue?

Comment: no issues while scrolling fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From discussion about how to use a table view for chat:
We can use a table view which uses a transform to flip the Y coordinate. We then need to do the same for each of the cells so they are not upside down.

The procedure is to build a normal messaging table view where the newest message is on top (instead of bottom). Then put the table view on some superview and invert its coordinate system:

```
chatContainer?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
```

The cell containing the messages should also have some sort of superview for all the contents which needs to be flipped:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        containerView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    }
```

So the cell is basically flipped twice so it is shown correctly.

You may find an example project [here](https://github.com/maticoblak/iOS---ChatTableView).

Comment: One comment, you can transform the cells and the tableView themselves no need to transform containers.

Comment: I know you can but I discourage you to do so. The table view might internally do some adjustments with the cells directly which may then break if you assign transform to them. The same goes for the whole table view. So please use that with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Use time profiler to identify where exactly is the issue. The thing is that in general the `UITableView` performance is not effected by a number of items loaded. The view itself will load as many items as it needs to fill the whole screen.

You may test this by logging a method in a `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So I am guessing this method may be the one that is slow. Check how you access the data from it, maybe there is some heavy logic on it. Or the cell layout may be bugged and very slow.

In a general case if you have extremely large amount of data consider using core data and `NSFetchedResultsController` which is designed specifically for this situations. But still note that loading 500 elements in a table view should work smoothly without any special optimizations.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake the block wasn't from the reloadData.
After loading i scroll to the bottom of the tableView and that blocks the thread.

tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Ah well that one might be a problem. Do you have fixed cell heights? Maybe try to compute the offset manually and use setContentOffset. I am not sure if it will fix it but do try.

Comment: No fixed heights. its a chat app so all height are dynamically calculated.
Is there maybe another way to flip the tableView to start from bottom?

Comment: So I assume the first load is the only problem and in it there is no reason to animate it. When you get the first batch try to use the estimated height to compute the initial offset. Then set this offset as non animated. After that call the first reloadData on the table view. Then after that use your method scrollToRow. If it doesn't work at all then first try to change the order so you call the reload first and then change the offset manually.

Comment: I must say in general we don't use table views for the messaging but rather a custom scroll view. The paging should be done as well. But since you are going this way you might simply try to flip the coordinate system. I am not sure if this would work just out of the box but it will not hurt to try it: Reverse the data source so the last message is the first in array. Then put the table view on some UIView which has a flipped transform (scale(1.0,-1.0)). This should produce a flipped view. Now also flip each of the cells. So ensure that the cell has another view with the same flipped transform.

Comment: Thanks, but both ways didn't change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136437/discussion-between-matic-oblak-and-ilan).

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this; If user scroll down from top to bottom of the tableview scrollview delegate method fire its "scrollViewDidScroll" method and detect if user bottom of tableview or not then fetch other data and append your array and reload the tableview. Thats it!

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{   
    CGFloat actualPosition = scrollView_.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView_.contentSize.height - (someArbitraryNumber);
    if (actualPosition >= contentHeight) {
        [self.newsFeedData_ addObjectsFromArray:self.newsFeedData_];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
}
```

Comment: that is not a good idea, you will get a lagging user experience on scrolling and also in general, why would you reload all the data on any scroll event. this will freeze the app even more

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this solution, didn't had that problem myself.
Maybe just dispatch it?

```
extension UITableView {

func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {

            let numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections
            let numberOfRows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)
            if numberOfRows > 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, thats the problem I have with it too. Have you tried it? On the other hand you are not animating it. I have seen some examples dispatching it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244293/scrolltorowatindexpath-with-uitableview-does-not-work), but I cant really test this out right now.

Comment: not working.

it doesn't scroll and then when the user scrolls it crashes with some thread problem

Comment: not working, it shows the top of the tableview then the thread is blocked and after that it jumps to the last cell

Comment: and you are sure that the thread gets blocked by `scrollToRow`?

Comment: yes, i have logs with times and scrollToRow takes about 3 seconds.
When i remove it everything works.