# What is a good way of organising reusable ViewControl code for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for a good ideas of organising a reusable code for my swift project. I would like to note that I am a beginner to swift and mobile development.

For example scroll table view to the top/bottom, show dialog or even go to another View and so on.

All this things contain 3-6 lines of the same code. It it doens't look particularly good to have the same 3-6 lines of codes in almost each view. So I am thinking to create a class with static functions that I can call from each view. For example to scroll table:

```
func scrollTable(to position:UITableViewScrollPosition, ofTable tableView: UITableView){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
            let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections
            let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)

            if numberOfRows > 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

> code is based on [scrollToRowAtIndexPath with UITableView does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244293/scrolltorowatindexpath-with-uitableview-does-not-work)

Is it a good bad idea? May be somebody can recommend something better.

Comment: Where's the repetition of code? What's supposed to be "reusable" here?

Comment: So each time for example when in ViewContoller I need to scroll table I am using this code that I have shown. It looks a waistage to copy it to each controller. So I am looking for a good ideas in the industry...

Comment: Then why not extend UIViewController? I don't see what "a class with static functions" has to do with this; that seems mighty heavy-handed to me.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you. That was a reason for the question. To find a good ideas about how to organise the code in better and more professional way. I like your idea. It sounds better than creating a separate class with static functions..

Comment: A "class with (only) static functions" is almost never a good approach in Swift. That exists in Java because of limitations in the language that don't exist in Swift.

Comment: Thank you Rob for explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in this function is already local, so it's just a function. You can extract that function into its own file and use it everywhere. There's no need to make it static. That said (and without having much opinion on whether this is a good function or not), in Swift it would generally be an extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scroll(to position: UITableViewScrollPosition) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
            let numberOfRows = numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)

            if numberOfRows > 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
                scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This is a strange function because it seems to ignore its `position` parameter, so I think it should be rewritten somewhat. But even so, this is the basic approach if you want a reusable function.)

Comment: Just had a thought: there's no way in Swift to say of an extension method, "this method should be callable only by UIViewController subclasses" or similar, is there? That would require some sort of `protected` access control, right?

Comment: No. There's no inheritance-based access levels in Swift. It's difficult to imagine a case where that would be a useful for this case (UIViewControllers shouldn't expose their UIViews, so it shouldn't matter). But even in cases where it could be useful, that basic concept doesn't exist in Swift (and is unlikely to be added).

Comment: Thank you very much Rob for a good explanation. So the best option to create in separate file subclass of for example UIViewController with list of extensions, in another file subclass of UITableView with own extensions and then instead of using standart UIViewController use my own classes. Is it correct?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The above code is an extension on *UITableView*, not UITableViewController. I would just include it in project where you wanted that. If you want extensions on UITableViewController, then make it an extension there. There's no need for special subclasing.

Comment: Sorry, I mean UITableView. So for example if I do have three different instances of UITableView (on different views), the best option would be just create the same extension for each of them with the same code?

Comment: Three instances of `UITableView` will all get the same extension. Extensions aren't on individual instances; it's on all instances of the type. So the above code would make this method available for all your tables, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a custom method along with its implementation into any UIViewController subclass by writing an *extension* of UIViewController.